# For some reason Flutter are ignoring my list.map

Tags: flutter, dart

The problem is in `decoded.map`,  I don't know why Flutter is ignoring this.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class HomeController {
  String cellphone = '';
  String message = '';
  String generatedURL = '';

  List<PreviousMessage> previousMessages = List<PreviousMessage>();

  Future loadPreviousMessages() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String savedString = prefs.getString('history');
    List decoded = json.decode(savedString);
    decoded.map((e) {previousMessages.add(PreviousMessage(cellphone: e.cellphone, message: e.message));});
    print(decoded);
    print(previousMessages);
  }
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the forEach method and not the map method, also you need to add a  "return" key word inside a map or forEach unless you use the "=>" syntax. Further, if you're looking for syntax help, this is dart language and not flutter, flutter is a ui framework, dart is the language. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.map returns a new lazy Iterable with elements that are created by calling f on each element of this Iterable in iteration order.

since it is lazy Iterable the function won't be called unless the returned iterable is re-iterated.

for example

```
var x = <int>[1,2,3,4,5,6];
x.map((i)=>print('in map $i'));
```

Here the 2nd line won't print any value as we are not iterating over the returned value from the .map function

```
x.map((i)=>print('in map $i')).toList();
```

But if we iterate over the returned value, the passed function is executed and values will be printed.

Hope it makes clear why your `decoded.map` is not working.

You can use .forEach to iterate, that should work fine.

Comment: i will take a look, thank you for the response :)